# Timeout on VNC VIEWER connect running latest 64 bit OS

Tags: vnc

I've just installed the 64 bit version of raspos and am getting a timeout attempting to connect vnc viewer.  (I can putty in without problems).

The log contains some suspicious entries, but I'm not sure how to interpret them.

Installed from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/raspios_lite_arm64-2021-04-09/

VNC install procedure:

```
b.  Update:
i.  sudo apt-get update -y
ii. sudo apt-get upgrade -y
iii.    sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
c.   Install VNC:
i.  sudo raspi-config
ii. Select Interfacing Options
iii.    Select VNC
iv. For the prompt to enable VNC, select Yes (Y)
v.  For the confirmation, select Ok
vi. Select Display Options
vii.    Select Resolution
viii.   Select anything but the default (example: 1024x768)
ix. Select Ok
```

Log details:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/debian_version
10.9
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v8+ #1414 SMP PREEMPT Fri Apr 30 13:23:25 BST 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat  /home/pi/.vnc/raspberrypi:1.log
XvncSession start time: 2021-05-20T21:24:34.088Z

pulseaudio not installed
Starting Xvnc
Waiting for Xvnc...
VNC(R) Server 6.7.2 (r43081) ARMv8-A (Sep 21 2020 00:15:42)
Copyright (C) 2002-2020 RealVNC Ltd.
RealVNC and VNC are trademarks of RealVNC Ltd and are protected by trademark
registrations and/or pending trademark applications in the European Union,
United States of America and other jurisdictions.
Protected by UK patent 2481870; US patent 8760366; EU patent 2652951.
See https://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
For third party acknowledgements see:
https://www.realvnc.com/docs/6/foss.html
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10, Linux 5.10.17, aarch64
<13> 2021-05-20T21:24:34.151Z raspberrypi Xvnc[666]: ServerManager: Server started
Underlying X server release 609000, The X.Org Foundation

error opening security policy file /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/TTF/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/CID/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Starting dbus
dbus started
Starting xstartup
xstartup started
/etc/vnc/xstartup: 27: /etc/vnc/xstartup: xsetroot: not found
Starting session: /etc/X11/Xsession
dbus-daemon[683]: [session uid=1000 pid=683] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.0' (uid=1000 pid=695 comm="dbus-update-activation-environment --verbose --sys")
dbus-daemon[683]: [session uid=1000 pid=683] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Session terminated with return code 1
xstartup terminated
Sending TERM signal to Xvnc...
FreeFontPath: FPE "/usr/share/vnc/fonts/" refcount is 2, should be 1; fixing.
<13> 2021-05-20T21:24:34.485Z raspberrypi Xvnc[666]: ServerManager: Server stopped
Xvnc terminated
Sending TERM signal to dbus...
dbus terminated

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ date
Thu 20 May 22:27:00 BST 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by:

```
sudo apt install raspberrypi-ui-mods
```